# Azure Time Series - Can't get data

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I have set up an IotHub that receives messages from a device. The Hub is getting the messages, and I am able to see the information reaching and being processed in TSI.
[Metrics from TSI Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETMX.png)

However, when trying to view the data in the TSI enviroment I get an error message saying there is no data.

I think the problem might have to do with setting up the model. I have created an hierarchy, types, and an instance.

[model view - instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdpBP.png)

As I understand it the instance fields are what is need to reference the set of data. In my case, the Json message being pushed thru the IOT HUb has a field called dvcid, in which "1" is the name of the only device sending values.

Am I doing something wrong?

How can i check the data being stored in TSI, like the rows and columns?

Is there an tutorial or example online where I can see the raw data going in and the model creation based on that data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue when I first tried using TSI. My problem was due to the timestamp I sent that was not in a proper format (the formatter sent things like "/Date(1547048015593+0100)/", which is not a typical way of encoding dates). When I specified the 'o' date to string format, it worked fine afterwards:

```
message.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

Hope this helps
f

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
After a lot more time of debugging I finally found that the problem was in the Time Series ID Property. I had set up a proprety that was not in the package.